# Python, Mockito, Mocking Another Module's Imports

Tags: python, mockito

Suppose I have module1.py

```
from my_library import useful_function

def do_something(x):
    return useful_function(x)
```

I am testing module2.py

```
from module1 import do_something

def do_something_else(x):
    return do_something(x+1)
```

useful_function does database calls, and I would therefore like to stub it out to return a constant value.

How can I use mockito to stub out useful_function?  I have tried importing my_library, and using

```
when( my_library ).useful_function('abc').thenReturn(...)
```

but that does not work.  If I pause Eclipse and hover over the useful_function line inside do_something(), it appears that useful_function() has not been stubbed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import module1
module1.useful_function = Mock(...)
return do_something(x+1)
```